# How to handle a DbUpdateException with concurrency error without throwing an exception

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency

I am using entity framework and have an application number that is being stored. Each time it is updated I have concurrency token in cause there are concurrency issues so there are not 2 application numbers that are the same.

The concurrency token throws an error when it happens, but I need to then run the code again to just get the next number instead of throwing the error. We need to handle it on the back end. Before we would lock a table, but I have seen a few places the entity prefers concurrency tokens.

Below is the code that I have, issue being is when the exception is thrown, it runs the call again, but it ALWAYS throws an error.

**DbContext**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
     builder.Entity<ApplicationNumberHelper>()
        .Property(x => x.RowVersion)
        .IsConcurrencyToken()
        .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

      base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

**DTO**

```
public class ApplicationNumberHelper
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public long CurrentApplicationNumber { get; set; }

    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
  }
```

**CALL**

```
public string GetNextApplicationNumber(int branchNumber)
    {
      try
      {
        var applicationNumberHelper = this._context.ApplicationNumberHelper.FirstOrDefault();

        if (applicationNumberHelper != null)
        {
          applicationNumberHelper.CurrentApplicationNumber = applicationNumberHelper.CurrentApplicationNumber + 1;
        }
        else
        {
          applicationNumberHelper = new ApplicationNumberHelper
          {
            CurrentApplicationNumber = 1
          };
        }   

        this._context.ApplicationNumberHelper.Update(applicationNumberHelper);
        this._context.SaveChanges();

        return applicationNumberHelper.CurrentApplicationNumber;
      }
      catch (DbUpdateException ex)
      {
        return this.GetNextApplicationNumber(branchNumber);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and thought I would post it here since it was harder to find, and no one was able to help. I ended up changing the catch to the following

```
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
{
    ex.Entries.Single().Reload();
    this._context.SaveChanges();
    return applicationNumber;
}
```